# Schema.org markup for not visible elements

Tags: schema.org

Would it be valid to add Schema.org markup for elements, that are not visible on the page? For example the address of a location is shown on the page but the longitude and latitude are not shown. Could I still add the data for longitude and latitude in the Schema.org markup?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It's basically the same as when you "display" a price as `$ 16,95` but in schema-org markup you list it as `16.95`

Answer (score 1):

Google may interpret this as the **[spam signal for manual action](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175#zippy=%2Cstructured-data-issue)** on your website:

> **Structured data found on hidden content**
>
> Structured data found on
> elements that are not visible to the user.

I do not know of any reason that can prevent you from specifying geo coordinates explicitly in the content of the page that your structured data refers to.